# finding length of the list in android

Tags: android

I have a list which contains the list of wifi P2P devices , I want to find the length of the list so that I can send the connection request to each of the p2p device.

```
List<WifiP2pDevice> deviceList = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
```

Comment: use `deviceList.size()`

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size()
Its in the manual!

Comment: the Java tag boggles my mind sometimes

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `deviceList.size()` to find the size of the `List`.

Mind you, the returned value is the number of elements in the list which differs from the individual element's position on the list.
That is to say, for instance, `deviceList.size()` with a size of 5 the last element in the list has the position `size-1` or in this case 4.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) before asking here and avoid being downvoted (no offense).

To put it simple:

deviceList.size()